# Xubuntu 14.04 Synaptics Touchpad works on login screen, stops working after login

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, wine, touchpad, synaptics

The last thing I remember installing was Wine and some library (I'm new to linux and I've forgotten) and after I rebooted the touchpad would not work anymore. Let me know what other information you need and I can post it.

Comment: Well, I'd tried a few things and nothing worked. Logged out, logged in as Guest, logged back in and it's working again. I'd tried a relog before without any luck.

Sadly I can not recommend any methods to fix this problem for future readers.

Comment: Did you install the library in command line. You could use the `history` command to check what you installed.

Answer (score 0):

I updated Uubuntu on my laptop and the touchpad/mouse stopped working as well. After some searching, I found a temporary solution:

With `xinput` you can see the input hardware. Then giving 
`xinput --enable id` you can enable the chosen device.

I guess this is a bug of the last kernel, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a little override script. Put code below to /home/yourhome/bin (create the folder if it doesn't exist) as touchpad-repair.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

var=`xinput | grep "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"`;
var=`echo $var | grep -o "[0-9]\+\ \["`;
var=`echo $var | grep -o "[0-9]\+"`;
xinput --enable $var;
```

Then, all you need to do is enter "touchpad-repair.sh" (TAB key should help you) to console (runing inside graphical environment) every time touchpad is not working after login. (If you know how to run it automatically  after login into KDE, please share... What I tried never worked... I still have to do it manually.)